# Using a node from sourceNodes in schemaCustomization

Tags: graphql, gatsby

In my `gastby-node` file I have used `sourceNodes` to `createNode` from an API response. I would like to resolve this node in another type. The problem is that `createSchemaCustomization` runs before `sourceNodes` so the node type doesn't exist.

> Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was 'Error: Type with name "TYPE" does not exists'. Stacktrace was 'Error: Type with name "TYPE" does not exists

Something like this:

```
exports.sourceNodes = async ({
  actions: { createNode },
  createContentDigest,
  getNodesByType,
  createNodeId,
}) => {
  const data = getNodesByType('SOME_TYPE')

  data.forEach(async (item, idx) => {
    const result = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT)
    const resultData = await result.json()
    
    const data = resultData.response

    const nodeMeta = {
      id: item.id,
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: `TYPE`,
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(data)
      }
    }

    // create node for build time data example in the docs
    const node = Object.assign({}, data, nodeMeta)
    createNode(node)
  })
}

exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions, schema }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = [
    `type SOME_TYPE implements Node {
      extra_fields: TYPE @link(from: "item.id")
    }`
  ]
  //  
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

This does not work because the `TYPE` does not exist when `createSchemaCustomization` is called. In looking at the docs I'm seeing `createResolver` which might be what I'm looking for. Has anyone done something along these lines?

Comment: That's odd.. according to the docs, `actions.createTypes` is available in the `sourceNodes` hook as well, have you tried moving that chunk of code under sourceNodes?

Comment: Interesting, didn’t know I could use `createTypes` in `sourceNodes`. I got around it temporarily by extending a field, but there are advantages to making them nodes.

Comment: @DerekNguyen `createTypes` is only available in `createSchemaCustomization` according to the docs (in the small print) - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/actions/#createTypes

Comment: It seems I can create nodes in `sourceNodes` but not use them in `createSchemaCustomization`, or create nodes in `createSchemaCustomization` and still not use them in `@link` directives.

Comment: Ah that's weird, I see sourceNodes listed on the link to the [docs you shared](https://imgur.com/a/Tr34KS1). Any chance you could create a minimal repro?

Comment: @DerekNguyen I read that incorrectly, `createTypes` is also available in `sourceNodes`